Oledb mixed number/string CSV read
I use oledb to read csv:
Connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" +
                                 @"Data Source='" + Path.GetDirectoryName(FileWork) + "';" +
                                 @"Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""");

Connection.Open();
OriginTableName = "[" + Path.GetFileName(FileWork) + "]";
Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + OriginTableName, Connection);

This is my CSV:
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
ABC,DEF,GHI,"57/8",125
ABC,DEF,GHI,801,587

The problem is value 57/8 from the CSV is never read, this cell of the CSV always returns null string. When I delete second row of the CSV file, then it reads 57/8.
How to read mixed string/number columns?

I just tried the same data with the ACE driver (successor to JET) and got the same result. It seems that even with the quotes, the driver tries to convert the text into a number. And since it is not recognised as a valid number it returns a null. I tried various combinations, all of which failed.

Add IMEX=1 - this tells OLEDB that when mixed data types are found in the first 8 rows to return Text. While you would prefer a number, at least text can be parsed. To aid this you should use HDR=No and discard it. Also, use the newer driver as the Jet 4.0 is older than me and creaks just as much.

IMEX=1 ufortunately doesn't change anything in my case.

Off the top of my head... Scanrows=0  comes to mind. Scanrows being how many rows to read to establish the data type of any given column. Your data provider allows for custom schema files, you may want to look into that. Though your sample clearly contains 2 different data types, in the same column of 2 different records... What data type do you expect out of it? Once you established that, code the schema file accordingly, as well as the downstream code.

In my opionion,the csv is truely a text.
Why you don't try to use the
File.ReadAllLines()

to get info from the csv？
